# Prove $\binom km\binom tk=\binom tm\binom{t-m}{t-k}$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

$$\binom km\binom tk=\binom tm\binom{t-m}{t-k}\\m\le k\le t$$
I'm not sure where to start. Combinatorics has confused me, as there doesn't seem to be a place in the textbook to read about it, and the solutions have been far too difficult to think about. Is there a strategy to this?

Answer (score 4):

If what you want is a scenario or a procedure that might help you understand what the identity is about, here's one:

Imagine you're a producer of a sitcom and your task is to select $\color{blue} m$ cast members out of $\color{red} t$ candidates via a two-stage process: first you narrow it down to $\color{orange} k$ candidates, then out of these $\color{orange} k$ you get the final $\color{blue} m$. The cast should have a good chemistry so you'll pick a combo of $\color{blue} m$ together all at once as opposed to picking a person for each role one by one.

How many possible ways are there to do this? It's the L.H.S. of the identity $${t \choose k}{k \choose m}$$

At the same time, the cruel reality of the TV industry is that you actually have already decided the cast (of size $\color{blue} m$ out of $\color{red} t$), and the two-stage process is just a formality. Here what you need to do (to put up a show for the public) is to pick ${\color{orange} k}-\color{blue} m$ people (who you are going to discard anyway in the 2nd stage) out of the pool of `losers' of size ${\color{red} t}-\color{blue} m$, to team them up with the predetermined $\color{blue} m$ to form the $\color{orange} k$ temporary winners of the 1st stage.

How many possible situations are there for this? It's the R.H.S. of the identity $${t \choose m}{t-m \choose k-m}$$

Comment: Nice solution, +1

Answer (score 2):

Expand the binomial coefficients into factorials:
$$\binom km\binom tk=\frac{k!t!}{m!k!(k-m)!(t-k)!}$$
This simplifies to
$$\frac{t!}{m!(k-m)!(t-k)!}$$
Multiply both halves of the fraction by $(t-m)!$, then rearrange:
$$\frac{\color{blue}{t!}(t-m)!}{\color{blue}{m!(t-m)!}(k-m)!(t-k)!}=\color{blue}{\binom tm}\binom{t-m}{t-k}$$
Hence
$$\binom km\binom tk\equiv\binom tm\binom{t-m}{t-k}$$

Comment: @JaredY "I don't think this is right" This comment is quite out of line. The post perfectly answers your question (whose lack of context is annoying, by the way). If you are after words-only answers, you should mention it in the question (and next time, using the term "bijective proof" would be a plus).

Answer (score 1):

Expanding them as factorials,

\begin{eqnarray}
\binom{k}{m}\binom{t}{k}=\frac{\color{red}{k!}}{m!(k-m)!}\frac{t!}{\color{red}{k!}(t-k)!}
 &=&\frac{t!}{m!(k-m)!(t-k)!}\\
 &=&\frac{t!\color{red}{(t-m)!}}{m!\color{red}{(t-m)!}(k-m)!(t-k)!}\\
 &=&\frac{\color{orange}{t!}\color{green}{(t-m)!}}{\color{orange}{m!{(t-m)!}}\color{green}{(k-m)!(t-k)!}}\\
 &=&\frac{t!}{m!(t-m)!}\frac{(t-m)!}{(t-k)!(k-m)!}=\binom{t}{m}\binom{t-m}{t-k}
\end{eqnarray}

---

(This is basically the same as Parcly's. I just wanted to try out the colors like he did.)